# Rust return trait object from Option.unwrap_or() for T: IntoIterator

Tags: rust

Here is the [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf227d2f7e36295c1266631e76ecbec5), also the code snippet as below:

```rust
fn test_inner<Tag: AsRef<str>, Tags: IntoIterator<Item = Tag> + std::fmt::Debug>(tags: Tags) {
    println!("{:?}", tags);
}

fn test<Tag: AsRef<str>, Tags: IntoIterator<Item = Tag> + std::fmt::Debug>(tags: Option<Tags>) {
    test_inner(tags.unwrap_or(["abc"]));
    // test_inner(tags.unwrap_or(["abc"].into_iter()));
}

fn main() {
    test(None::<&[&str]>);
}
```

Now i got error:

```
|     test_inner(tags.unwrap_or(["abc"]));
|                               ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `Tags`, found array `[&str; 1]`
|
  = note: expected type parameter `Tags`
                      found array `[&str; 1]`
```

How should i return a trait object from the `tags.unwrap_or()` to satisfy the `T: <Tag: AsRef<str>, Tags: IntoIterator<Item = Tag>>`?

I am still learning rust, and my intention is wrapping the inner method so that the external caller can pass `None` to the `tags` parameter, if the approach direction is totally wrong, pls help to correct it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're aware of that option, but a simple way to write `test` is using an explicit `if`:

```
fn test<Tag: AsRef<str>, Tags: IntoIterator<Item = Tag> + std::fmt::Debug>(tags: Option<Tags>) {
    if let Some(tags) = tags {
        test_inner(tags)
    } else {
        test_inner(["abc"])
    }
}
```

The difference between this and the version with `unwrap_or()` is that this uses two different types in two different calls to `test_inner()`. The version with `unwrap_or()` attempts to come up with a single value of type `Tags`, and that can't work because it's the caller who gets to choose the type of `Tags`. A specific value like `["abc"]` simply doesn't have the same type as the generic type determined by the caller.

Comment: ah, thanks, now i understand the root cause

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do it, thanks for ur help and this reminder